# how to call asm funcion from c using NASM?

Tags: gcc, assemblies, nasm

I am using `ubuntu 14.10` , `64 bit` system.

I need to call a function which is in .asm file from c code.
i need to execute a 32 bit program.

How I can compile and link both code ?
When I run c code it should call the function in assembly file and print something.

I tried below c code,

```
int main()
{   
    int ret_status;   
    ret_status = asm_main();  
    return ret_status; 
}
```

Can anyone give me a sample of 32 bit asm code and compile and linking methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling assembly routines from C source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171522/calling-assembly-routines-from-c-source-code)

Comment: I've submitted this question as a possible duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171522/calling-assembly-routines-from-c-source-code). It has an example of how this is supposed to work using `nasm` and some problems you might encounter.